# How to clean less than 2*2 pixel areas in a grey scale image?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I got a Image Pixels array, the image is a grey scale image, which means the RGB are the same value. And I have the width and height of this image. I am going to replace the areas which equals or less than 2*2 with RED colour.

I had thinking about using (for each) to enumerate all the points in the image, and for each image, I check the 3*3 area of that pixel, check if this pixel is exactly less than or equals to 3*3, but I think this way is too stupid. Is there any other faster way to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

DATA EXAMPLE:
Image resolution: 2*2
Image Array: [255, 0, 255, 125]

Comment: What do you mean "areas which equals or less than 2*2"? I don't know what you're saying. Are you talking about 2x2 square areas, or you want to clean up pixels with RGB values less than 4 (i.e. nearly black)?

Comment: sorry for explain so stupid. I mean 2x2 square areas...